# How to get user session in Cognito after sign up or login via Google?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito

I set up authorization and login in the Cognito via Google. Now I need to get to the user attributes, but I don't understand how can I do it? Existing apis like getSession don't work,and throwing an error.

I use React and library 'amazon-cognito-identity-js'.

I loggin via Google this way:

```
const path = `https://${myDomain}.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/login?response_type=code&client_id=${clientId}&redirect_uri=${redirect}`;
router.push(path);
```

My email appears in User Pool - that's OK.

After successful redirect I call this code, because I need a session to get the user attributes:

```
const getSession = (role: TRoles): Promise<IReturnObj> => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const user = MyPool.getCurrentUser();

if (!user) {
  reject(new Error('Current user not found'));
}

user.getSession((err: Error, session: CognitoUserSession) => {
  if (err) {
    reject(err);
  } else {
    resolve({session, user});
  }
    });
  });
};
```

In result I get undefined user and reject error. What I doing wrong?

[My Cognito app client settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YM6v4.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new `CognitoUserSession` using credentials in your `redirect_uri`. You will be able to use `getSession` successfully once a `CognitoUserSession` has been created and all relevant credentials have been stored in your cookies.

Example:

redirect_uri

```
https://www.example.com#access_token={{accessToken}}&id_token={{idToken}}&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600
```

Import relevant objects

```
import {
    CognitoUser,
    CognitoAccessToken,
    CognitoIdToken,
    CognitoRefreshToken,
    CognitoUserSession,
} from "amazon-cognito-identity-js";
```

Then extract accessToken, idToken, and create your session as follows:

```js
const AccessToken = new CognitoAccessToken({
    AccessToken: accessToken,
});
const IdToken = new CognitoIdToken({ IdToken: idToken });

const RefreshToken = new CognitoRefreshToken({
    RefreshToken: idToken,
});

const sessionData = {
    IdToken,
    AccessToken,
    RefreshToken,
};

const userSession = new CognitoUserSession(sessionData);

const userData = {
    Username: email, // get this from token/another method
    Pool,
};

const cognitoUser = new CognitoUser(userData);
cognitoUser.setSignInUserSession(userSession);

cognitoUser.getSession((err, session) => {
    if (session.isValid()) {
        // access your session
    }
    // throw error
});
```